# How to make a AJAX driven board in a Snake and ladder turn based game which updates with players playing in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multiplayer

I am working on developing a Multiplayer turn based Snake & Ladder game using HTML/JS(Front-end), PHP/MySQL back ended.

It is a AJAX driven game.
I have successfully done the following:

1. Created a login/Register page storing values in the database.
2. Upon Login -> Clicking on a button called 'multiplayer game': the user will be directed to a Chat-room where he can select a player with whom he needs to play.
3. Have implemented the AJAX driven chat system so real time chatting is achieved.
4. Once a user selects a player, both there pages get updated with against whom they are playing but not the board(since board is not written to implement ajax as of now)
   Have been utilizing resources in the web and developing this game. ***But now the issue I am having is:***
   I have designed the board game logic in Javascript and upon rolling of dice the two players move along the board. ***THIS BOARD IS FOR NOW NOT AJAX DRIVEN i.e, if Player1 makes a move, the move has to be updated in the Player 2 board as well***.[image]
   **ABOVE SCREENSHOT:** When two players I registered and logged in 'Chris' & 'Paul' for instance are in there respective boards and you can see there chats too work. But When I click on the 'Roll Dice' button, the players indicated by white and yellow move just in one board, which is logical since I have just created two players in Javascript and wrote the logic(They are not yet related to Crane and Chris).
   **BOARD.JS** file below:

   var player1 = $("#UserName").val();

   ```
   var player2 = $("#Opponent").val();

   var gameId = $("#GameId").val();

   console.log("name of first player: ",player1);

   console.log("name of second player: ",player2);

   console.log("Game ID is: ",gameId);//getting above values through session variables

   window.rollDice = ()=>{  
         const max = 6;
         const roll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
         $('.rolledValue').html("Rolled Dice Value is: " + roll);
         console.log("You rolled", roll);
         let currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerTurn];
         currentPlayer.position += roll;
         ladders.forEach(ladder=>{
           if (ladder.start === currentPlayer.position) {
             console.log("You stepped on a ladder!");
             currentPlayer.position = ladder.end;
           }
         });
         if (currentPlayer.position === position) {
           console.log("Player has won!");
           hasWon = true;
         }
         if (currentPlayer.position === position) {
           const diff = currentPlayer.position - position;
           currentPlayerPosition = position - diff;
         }

         currentPlayerTurn ++;
         if (currentPlayerTurn >= players.length) {
           currentPlayerTurn = 0;
         }
         renderBoard();
       }

       const players = [{
         name: player1,
         position: 0,
         color: "gold"
       },{
         name:player2,
         position: 0,
         color: "white"
       }];

       let currentPlayerTurn = 0;

       const width = 9;
       const height = 9;
       const board = [];
       let position = 0;
       let blackSquare = false;
       const ladders = [{
         start: 2,
         end: 22
       },{
         start: 50,
         end: 34
       },{
         start: 10,
         end: 44
       },{
         start: 61,
         end: 19
       },{
         start: 70,
         end: 83
       },{
         start:78,
         end: 4
       }];

       for (var y = height; y >= 0; y--) {
         let row = [];

         board.push(row);
         for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {

           row.push({x,y,occupied:null,position,color: blackSquare ? "steelblue" : "silver"});
           blackSquare = !blackSquare;
           position ++;
         }
       }

       const boardSizeConst = 50;
       const renderBoard = ()=>{
         let boardHTML = ``;
         board.forEach(row=>{
           row.forEach(square=>{
             boardHTML += `<div class=square style="top:${square.y * boardSizeConst}px; left:${square.x * boardSizeConst}px; background-color:${square.color}"></div>`
           });
         });

         players.forEach(player=>{
           let square = null;
           board.forEach(row=>{
           row.forEach(square=>{
                 if (square.position === player.position) {
                   boardHTML += `<div class=player style="top:${square.y * boardSizeConst + 5}px; left:${square.x * boardSizeConst + 5}px;background-color:${player.color}"></div>`;
                 }
             });
           });
         });

         ladders.forEach(ladder=>{

           //let start = 0;
           let startPos = {x:0,y:0};
           let endPos = {x:0,y:0};

           board.forEach(row=>{
             row.forEach(square=>{
               if (square.position === ladder.start) {
                 startPos.x = square.x * boardSizeConst;
                 startPos.y = square.y * boardSizeConst;
               }

               if (square.position === ladder.end) {
                 endPos.x = square.x * boardSizeConst;
                 endPos.y = square.y * boardSizeConst;
               }
             });
           });

           const isLadder = ladder.end > ladder.start;

           drawLine({color : isLadder ? "green" : "red",startPos,endPos});
         });
         document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = boardHTML;
       }
   ```

However, for now circles are not related to them. But I want to create a mechanism 'When Chris rolls dice in his board, it has to get updated in Crane board & vice-versa.

Need help. I am newbie to php but kind of have come till this point. 
[image]

Comment: That's quite some bunch of js code and logic to understand for us to even start thinking about the (not shown) php part of it. _But:_ the only question is how to update a move from player 1 to player 2, right?

Comment: You already have _"Once a user selects a player, both there pages get updated"_, I don't see what is so much different to _"if Player1 makes a move, the move has to be updated in the Player 2 board"_

Comment: @Jeff chat logic is ajax driven, but board as of now is written in plane js, would like to know how to make this board ajax driven so that both players can see updates respectively in there browsers.

Comment: @coder kemp you have to use websockets to get real time update, across user/browsers. more https://socket.io/

Comment: @ShishirAroraI am already using ajax for chat functionality, do you mean to say just for the board logic I can use web sockets? can you brief a bit about this

Comment: Ajax may not be a good idea for chat.It can easily be hacked.